# Custom the default login page Alfresco

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, alfresco

I want to custom my login page alfresco from the default one (4.2.f). I only want to change the alfresco logo and the background color. I think that I can copy files about login page ALfresco and copy them to the extension mechanism. 
I can't find those file in the alfresco path ?

Please, can someone can help me to figure it out ?

Comment: Is your question about webclient or share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the forums (and search it) you'll find a lot of topics regarding this.

For example: https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/share-login-page-42c-12282012-1507

It's best to do it with the extensions module, like this:

```
<extension>
    <modules>
        <module>
            <id>Custom Login Logo</id>
            <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
            <customizations>
                <customization>
                    <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.guest</targetPackageRoot>
                    <sourcePackageRoot>nl.contezza.components.login</sourcePackageRoot>
                </customization>
            </customizations>
        </module>
    </modules>
</extension>
```

Answer (score -3):

Are you talking about Alfresco Explorer or Alfresco Share?
Edit. Sorry missed the comment which already asked the same thing.

Edit. Why would you do that? I only asked a question because yours is not complete. And you tagged this question with nonsense tags. Please.

Anyway here are both of the solutions:

> If you need to customise Alfresco Explorer login page
> https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Customising_The_Login_Page
>
> Alfresco Share login:
> http://fcorti.com/2013/08/12/customize-alfresco-share-login-light-theme/
>
> If you want a better Share approach you could just override the login
> page:
> https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/tutorial-share-override-login-page.html

I hope it helps. Next time, Google first, or read the official documentation. Thanks.